# Что возвращает GetModuleHandle(NULL)

Tags: c++, header, pe, handle

Необходимо получить адрес начала PE-заголовка в памяти.
Использую данный код:

```
#define MakePtr(Type, Base, Offset) ((Type)(DWORD(Base) + (DWORD)(Offset)))


HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pDosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)hModule;
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pNTHeaders = MakePtr(PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS,hModule,pDosHeader-
>e_lfanew);
PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER pSections = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(pNTHeaders);
```

При выводе переменных получаю данные значения:

```
hModule = 01000000 //дескриптор файла
pDoaHeader = 01000000 //начало Dos заголовка
pDosHeader->e_lfanew = 224
pNTHeaders = 010000E0 // начало PE заголовка 
pSections = 010001D8
```

Вопрос в том почему используется хэндл(дескриптор файла) для нахождения DOS и PE заголовков? Какое он имеет отношение к структуре самого файла? А то получается какому то непонятному числу присваивается тип PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER и выдается по сути за начало файла. Разве DOS заголовок не идет от начала файла т.е. от 00000000?

Answer (score 4):

`GetModuleHandle` возвращает хэндл текущего исполнимого модуля (EXE).

В текущих версиях Windows, *кажется*, его значение равно указателю на базовый адрес модуля. Если формат вашего исполнимого файла начинается с `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER`'а, то в начале его образа у вас действительно найдётся `PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER`. (DOS-заголовок идёт с начала файла, да — но нулевой адрес файла не означает нулевой адрес модуля: по адресу 0 расположена страница, которая вызывает access violation при обращении!)

Подтверждение: [*The Old New Thing: Accessing the current module’s HINSTANCE from a static library*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041025-00/?p=37483). (Плюс вам понадобится также «известный» факт, что `HINSTANCE` приложения и `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` одинаковы.)

Тем не менее, я не нашёл упоминания этих фактов в официальной документации, поэтому я бы рассматривал их как ничем не подкреплённый хак. Стоит ли полагаться на него в вашем коде — решать вам.

Comment: Мелкомягкие не могут изменить это поведение, потому что обратная совместимость. От всех голых указателей в хэндлах, от которых они хотели избавиться, они уже избавились при переходе на 9x. Вряд ли будут что-то менять.

Comment: @Squidward: Ну, у них иногда возникают не-указатели. Например, [на границе 32- и 16-битного кода](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031201-00/?p=41673). И со store apps формат вполне может поменяться (а если кто-то рассчитывает на DOS Header, то он ССЗБ).